# User activation in wordpress

Tags: user-registration, user-meta

I want my users to first to activate their accounts so they can use all the features in the site.
There is a field in `wp_users` table named `user_status` which its default value is `0`.
I wonder what's that field for?
Should I use a `user_meta` to indicate the activation status of my users.

P.S. The registration of users is handled manually through a plugin I'm writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use my own usermeta to handle it to avoid having any sort of crossover issues with plugins/future updates. It should also allow you greater flexibility in what you store in the usermeta.